# JMockit passing same argument in the mocked method as actual method is getting

Tags: jmockit

I'm trying to write getter and setter mock methods which seem to be doing some database operation internally. Getter returns a String and setter takes String as argument. I would like to pass whatever I get from getter to the setter instead of passing a mock String so as to keep track of data flow.

Is there a way to pass the same String what actual setter is getting, to the mock method.

Please direct if there's a solution already available for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `MockUp` subclass with suitable `@Mock` method implementations for the getters/setters of interest. The setter would simply store the value in an instance field, which the getter would read. The same mechanism can be implemented with `Delegate` objects, if use of the "Expectations" API is preferred.